# ValueError: The user feature matrix specifies more features than there are estimated feature embeddings: 19400 vs 81728

Tags: python, machine-learning, matrix, lightfm

I have the following datasets:

Users:
10.000 Rows.

Features: User-Id, name, age, los, ou, gender, skills, language, grade, career interests

Trainings:
Training-Id, training name, main skill

Trainings Taken
User-Id, Training-Id, TrainingTaken
TrainingTaken will be a 10 when the user took the training, otherwise it wont appear in the dataset

The idea is to make a recommneder for trainings

I used this helper class for the matrices. https://github.com/Med-ELOMARI/LightFM-Dataset-Helper

```
from lightfm_dataset_helper.lightfm_dataset_helper import DatasetHelper
```

I defined the feature columns for user and trainings.

```
items_column = "Training-Id"
user_column = "User-Id"
ratings_column = "TrainingTaken"

items_feature_columns = [
    "training name",
    "main skill"
]

user_features_columns = ["name","age","los","ou", "gender", "skills", "language", "grade", "career interests"]
```

Then I build the matrices

```
dataset_helper_instance = DatasetHelper(
    users_dataframe=usersdf,
    items_dataframe=trainingsdf,
    interactions_dataframe=trainingstakendf,
    item_id_column=items_column,
    items_feature_columns=items_feature_columns,
    user_id_column=user_column,
    user_features_columns=user_features_columns,
    interaction_column=ratings_column,
    clean_unknown_interactions=True,
)
dataset_helper_instance.routine()
```

Then I train:

```
from lightfm import LightFM
from lightfm.cross_validation import random_train_test_split
(train, test) = random_train_test_split(interactions=dataset_helper_instance.interactions, test_percentage=0.2)

model = LightFM(loss='warp')

model.fit(
    interactions=dataset_helper_instance.interactions,
    sample_weight=dataset_helper_instance.weights,
    item_features=dataset_helper_instance.item_features_list,
    user_features=dataset_helper_instance.user_features_list,
    verbose=True,
    epochs=20,
    num_threads=20,
)
```

then I try to use the predict

```
import numpy as np
from lightfm.data import Dataset
#predict existing users
scores = model.predict(user_ids=81727, item_ids=[1])
print(scores)
```

However I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: The user feature matrix specifies more features than there are estimated 
feature embeddings: 19400 vs 81728.
```

what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be that LightFM's *internal* user_ids differs from that you have in your dataset. In your case internal user_ids probably are just integers in range(0, len(user_ids)). Similar for internal item_ids

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).